# How search word in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I will made a intelligence search with javascript. I have a string with a text and i will find the word in the search box and than set new var with result.
What are the methods of javascript which can i use?

Comment: Are you looking for Angular or vanilla JavaScript? What have you tried?

Comment: Give an example, or explain it better. AngularJS can search by `ng-model` with a filter in `ng-repeat`

Comment: You can try this code ,  
  

    <html>
    <title>
    Usman
    </title>
    <head>
    <script>
    
       //java script code    
     
    var str = "Muhammad Usman";
    if(str.indexOf("Muhammad") + 1) 
    {
       document.write("Found ...");
    }
    else
    {
    document.write("Not Found");
    }
    
    //ends here
    
    </script>
    </head>
    
    </html>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to look for a substring in a string.

For example, you can use [String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to determine the position of a substring in another string :

```js
var text = "Find me!";
var result = text.search("me");
console.log(result);
result = text.search("him");
console.log(result);
```

[String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof) does pretty much the same thing :

```js
var text = "Find me!";
var result = text.indexOf("me");
console.log(result);
result = text.indexOf("him");
console.log(result);
```

If you just want to know whether a string contains a certain substring, you could use [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)  :

```js
var text = "Find me!";
var result = text.includes("me");
console.log(result);
result = text.includes("him");
console.log(result);
```

If you have a search pattern to look for, you could use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

```js
var text = "Find me!";
var result = text.match(/me/);
console.log(result);
result = text.match(/him/);
console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you could use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) :

```js
var text = "Find me!";
var result = /me/.test(text);
console.log(result);
result = /him/.test(text);
console.log(result);
```

You could also use [a utility library like lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes) to do this for you :

```js
var text = "Find me!";
var result = _.includes(text, "me");
console.log(result);
result = _.includes(text, "him");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

See eg. [this benchmark](http://jsben.ch/COREJ) to compare the performance of each approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var str = "123test123";
if(str.indexOf("test") >= 0) {
   console.log("Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string variable you can use the include() method. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp